# symfony how encrypt route url not only url paramters use event listener?

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I want encode `admin/login` to base64(or others crypt):

> example: www.a.com/admin/login
>   encrypt: www.a.com/YWRtaW4vbG9naW4=

I want use Event Listener to decrypt url before route resolve,how can i do?

Comment: Why don't you simply write the encoded string into the route?

Comment: Thanks,i got it.